# PHP multiple MYSQL queries executed but only last one working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to run a couple of queries to swap sort order values within a database when up or down buttons are clicked however when he code below is executed on the 2nd query is ran.

```
if ($_POST['up']){
    $sort_this = $_POST['sort'];
    $sort_other = $_POST['sort'] - 1;

    $sql_this = "UPDATE portfolio SET sort = $sort_this -1 WHERE sort = $sort_this";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_this);

    $sql_other = "UPDATE portfolio SET sort = $sort_other +1 WHERE sort = $sort_other";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_other);
}
```

They both work perfectly fine on their own when i comment out the other, however when they are both display the problem is as above. I have also tried running it in a mysqli_multi_query however that didnt work either.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `$sort_other = $_POST['sort'] - 1;` and `SET sort = $sort_other +1` - Um... aren't you cancelling these out? Far as I remember my math, -1 plus +1 equal 0.

Comment: $sort_other = $_POST['sort'] - 1; is the identifier, for example if this row is 5, the other row is 5 - 1 = 4. SET sort = $sort_other +1 is what I want the new value to be, whether I use SET sort = $sort_other +1 or $sort_this they are both the same.

Comment: I added your comment to the question (as an edit) for clarification. You've been given an answer below also.

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of this? I see the word(s) "sort" and this suggests that you're probably wanting to run a SELECT query somewhere in order to "sort" columns; am I right on this? If not, you will need to elaborate on your question as to what the true purpose of what you're wanting to do "is".

Comment: In my database I have a column to sort which order the contents are displayed in. I am trying to implement up and down buttons where if I click up the row is then displayed above the previous row. for example if  I had 2 items in my database, apple and orange, with sort values 1 and 2 respectively, If i click up on orange its sort value becomes 1 and apples then becomes 2.

Comment: That's what I thought. Well Lee, your question is starting to grow as to what you really want to do here and you will need to provide us with the db schema as well as the query you're using on SELECT to show how you're wanting to sort these out. I made another edit to your question. You'll need to edit it yourself if there are other details we should know about.

Comment: Fred, thank you however this is seriously deviating from the original question. All I wanted to know was why the code wasn't working as expected. After the explanations given I know where I was going wrong, now I know I have implemented a fix. Instead of simply saying WHERE sort = $sort_other, I added AND id != $id so that the 2nd query doesn't change the row that was edited in the first query. I have seen this googled a fair bit so for anybody that wants to know this is the code I used:

Comment: if ($_POST['up']){
 $sort_this = $_POST['sort'];
 $sort_other = $_POST['sort'] - 1;
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 
 $sql_this = "UPDATE portfolio SET sort = $sort_this -1 WHERE sort = $sort_this";
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql_this);
 
 $sql_other = "UPDATE portfolio SET sort = $sort_other +1 WHERE sort = $sort_other AND id != $id";
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql_other);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the limited amount of data my best guess would be that they DO both execute but that they're not doing what you **think** they should be doing.

Say $_POST['sort'] is the number 3, this means $sort_this is also 3.
The first query will go through the database and update all 3's to a 2.

$sort_other will be 3-1 (2) and so the second query will go through the database and update all 2's to a 3. Effectively undoing what the first query did. (and altering any other 2's to 3's)

You will never see the end result of the first query because the third query will overwrite all changes the first query made.

Also, simply pasting in a variable into a query like you're doing is bad practice. It is prone to SQL injection. You can avoid this by using prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: A very good explanation which I guess is what I (basically) said in comments about -1 plus +1 cancelling themselves out. I edited the question with the OP's comment on what he'd like to achieve.

Comment: I could see what you were saying if they were both updating the same row, but they are updating different rows. $sort_this = 5, $sort other = 4. From the first query: WHERE sort = $sort_this. From the 2nd query: WHERE sort = $sort_other

Comment: Lee perkins, they are not updating different rows. The database changes between the two queries. Given the value of 5 (as per your new edit) sort_this would become "5" and sort_other would become 4.

first query would be
UPDATE portfolio SET sort = 4 WHERE sort = 5
after this all original 5's in the database will be 4's

second one would be:
UPDATE portfolio SET sort = 5 WHERE sort = 4

After this all 4's in the database (including those from the first query) will become 5's.

In doing so the second query reverses the first query :) Because all the 5's that became a 4 now become 5

Comment: Ahhh yeahh I see what you guys are saying now, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out. Back to the drawing board :(

Comment: Well, if you tell us what you need we might be able to help :)

Comment: Thanks :), as per my reply to Fred above...In my database I have a column to sort which order the contents are displayed in. I am trying to implement up and down buttons where if I click up the row is then displayed above the previous row. for example if I had 2 items in my database, apple and orange, with sort values 1 and 2 respectively, If i click up on orange its sort value becomes 1 and apples then becomes 2.

Comment: Try including the primary key (in my case orange): SET sort = sort -1 WHERE name = "orange"